# Iterate through JSON Object to get all objects with property

Tags: json, reactjs, parsing

I am trying to iterate through the following JSON document in order to get the names of skating rinks:

[image]

I can get one name; however, what I am trying to do is loop through all of the entries (there are 253) and return a list of all the names.

Here is my React component:

```
class Patinoire extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { patinoires: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var url = 'http://localhost:3000/patinoires'
        fetch(url).then(function(response) {
            if (response.status >= 400) {
                throw new Error("Bad response from server");
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => this.setState ({ patinoires: data.patinoires }));
    }

    render() {
        var patinoires = this.state.patinoires;
        var pjs2 = Object.values(patinoires);
        var pjs3 = pjs2.map(x => x["2"].nom);

        return <div>{pjs3}</div>
    }
}
```

Right now, when using {pjs3}, I get the name of 3rd skating rink of the JSON document. How can I loop through all the entries and return the name property of all the entries?

EDIT: here is a sample of the data

```
{
    "patinoires": {
        "patinoire": [
            {
                "nom": [
                    "Aire de patinage libre, De la Savane (PPL)"
                ],
                "arrondissement": [
                    {
                        "nom_arr": [
                            "Côte-des-Neiges - Notre-Dame-de-Grâce"
                        ],
                        "cle": [
                            "cdn"
                        ],
                        "date_maj": [
                            "2018-01-12 09:08:25"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "ouvert": [
                    ""
                ],
                "deblaye": [
                    ""
                ],
                "arrose": [
                    ""
                ],
                "resurface": [
                    ""
                ],
                "condition": [
                    "Mauvaise"
                ]
            },
            {
                "nom": [
                    "Aire de patinage libre, Georges-Saint-Pierre (PPL)"
                ],
                "arrondissement": [
                    {
                        "nom_arr": [
                            "Côte-des-Neiges - Notre-Dame-de-Grâce"
                        ],
                        "cle": [
                            "cdn"
                        ],
                        "date_maj": [
                            "2018-01-12 09:08:25"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "ouvert": [
                    ""
                ],
                "deblaye": [
                    ""
                ],
                "arrose": [
                    ""
                ],
                "resurface": [
                    ""
                ],
                "condition": [
                    "Mauvaise"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Which key name has the name of the iceskating rink? Array.prototype.reduce will be a better option if all the arrays have a name in it.

Comment: I believe the key name is "nom". Where should I use Array.prototype.reduce? Should I use it instead of ```Object.values(patinoires);```?

Comment: Try `var pjs3 = pjs2.map(x => x.nom);`

Comment: @CliveSeebregts it does not return anything, when I do a ```console.log(x.nom)``` it returns undefined.

Comment: post s sample of your data instead of the screenshot, that would be easier for people to try to help you. do you want to get all the `nom` values from each array?

Comment: Please post a sample of your data as suggested by @Sagivb.g

Comment: try `var patinoires = this.state.patinoires;` then `var pjs2 = Object.values(patinoires.patinoire);` and finally `var pjs3 = pjs2.map(x => x.nom);`

Comment: I guess my problem is that at first this data was stored in an XML using single element arrays. I find hard to work with this after converting to JSON format.

Comment: What is the `console.log(patinoires)` output within `render()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to flatten the result data with combination of [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Here is a running example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      patinoires: {
        patinoire: [
          {
            nom: ["Aire de patinage libre, De la Savane (PPL)"],
            arrondissement: [
              {
                nom_arr: ["Côte-des-Neiges - Notre-Dame-de-Grâce"],
                cle: ["cdn"],
                date_maj: ["2018-01-12 09:08:25"]
              }
            ],
            ouvert: [""],
            deblaye: [""],
            arrose: [""],
            resurface: [""],
            condition: ["Mauvaise"]
          },
          {
            nom: ["Aire de patinage libre, Georges-Saint-Pierre (PPL)"],
            arrondissement: [
              {
                nom_arr: ["Côte-des-Neiges - Notre-Dame-de-Grâce"],
                cle: ["cdn"],
                date_maj: ["2018-01-12 09:08:25"]
              }
            ],
            ouvert: [""],
            deblaye: [""],
            arrose: [""],
            resurface: [""],
            condition: ["Mauvaise"]
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }

  renderData = () => {
    const { patinoires } = this.state;
    const markup = patinoires.patinoire.reduce((result, current) => {
      current.nom.map(n => {
        return result.push(<div>{n}</div>);
      });
      return result;
    }, []);
    return markup;
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderData()}</div>;
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You are a boss. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var pjs2 = Object.values(patinoires);
var names = pjs2.reduce((accumulator, elem) => {
   if (elem.patinoire) {
       elem.patinoire.forEach(part => {
           if(part.nom) {
              part.nom.forEach((name) => accumulator.push(name));
           }
       });
   }
   return accumulator;
}, []);
```